# creating rings with regions openstack swift

Tags: openstack, regions, openstack-swift

I installed `swift` on a `multi-node cluster` by following instructions from http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/howto_installmultinode.html. I wanted to add two `regions` to my `swift` installation. I tried to build the ring with the command

`swift-ring-builder account.builder add r1z1-$STORAGE_LOCAL_NET_IP:6002/$DEVICE $WEIGHT`

but, this is not a valid command and in the man page of swift-ring-builder, I can find only `swift-ring-builder account.builder add z1-$STORAGE_LOCAL_NET_IP:6002/$DEVICE $WEIGHT`.
How do I add the feature of regions (implemented since version 1.9 of swift)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I actually had installed `swift` from `ubuntu` repositories on `Ubuntu 12.04`. The problem is that only `swift 1.4.8` is supported from ubuntu repositories. To upgrade to the latest version, run the commands
`sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:icehouse`
and then, `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get update`